# How to change the background color of tab bar and tab icon in Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I want to know how to change the background color of this tab bar as Ionic 4.

I tried to add the `--background: white;` in ion-tab/ion-tabs but it doesn't work.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="Home" icon="home" href="/tabs/(home:home)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="About" icon="information-circle" href="/tabs/(about:about)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="about"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Contact" icon="contacts" href="/tabs/(contact:contact)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="contact"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I'm so curious about this new Ionic 4 :( Please help...

Comment: Did you override the variables? https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Ionic 4+**

```
ion-tab-bar, ion-tab-button{
 background-color: #ce0013;
}

ion-icon{
  color: #d7d8da;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add properties called color. Ionic 4 has predefined colors:

- primary
- secondary
- tertiary

More info in [documentation](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs/#properties)

Sample usage:

`<ion-tabs main color="primary">`

Answer (score 0):

Give `ion-tab` a class name like

```
<ion-tab class="tab"></ion-tab>
```

Now in the scss file provide the background-color for the class named tab

```
.tab{
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Say for eg you are working on home page it will have a home.scss file where you have to make the styling edits for the home.html (frontend)