# How to change background color of ionic 4 tab component

Tags: ionic-framework, themes

I'm creating an ionic 4 application. using the Tab component to present 3 tabs. the default color of the tab component in ionic is blue. the default background color is white. I would like to change and choose another background color.

The documentation offer to add:

```
:root {
  --ion-tab-bar-background: red; // or some other color
}
```

It did not work for me.
I also tried to modify variables.scss in theme folder in ionic 4 application
this also did not work for me.
I also read other posts in SOF but nothing succeeds or relevant to ionic 4
for example this post:[How to change the background color of tab bar and tab icon in Ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114684/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-tab-bar-and-tab-icon-in-ionic-4) offer solutions that did not work for me

my basic template:

```
<ion-tabs main color="primary">
  <ion-tab-bar slot="top" >
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>tab1</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>tab2</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>tab3</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
 </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>


<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
      <ion-img src="./../../assets/background-for-baby-picture.jpg"></ion-img>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>guide</ion-card-subtitle>
       <ion-card-title>welcome</ion-card-title>
     </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>info </p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
   <ion-list lines="none">
     <ion-list-header>   
  </ion-list-header> 
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I tought you used ion-tab-bar like this https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tab-bar

Comment: I do have a main tab component with ion-tab-bar like: <ion-tabs main color="primary">
  <ion-tab-bar slot="top" >
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>עמוד הבית</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>מעקב האכלה</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>הגדרות</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>

Comment: is your template is in the right order ? if not can you reorder it ?